# Calculating Sample Size for Cluster Randomized Trials with Person-level or Cluster-Level Outcomes

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, clinical-trials, cluster-sample

I have been looking for a formula to calculate the estimated sample size for a two-level cluster-randomized controlled trial with cluster-level outcome data. To my reading, several authors do not make this distinction in their formulae; they refer to a 'group mean difference' or 'effect size' without specifying whether it is at the individual-level or cluster-level (assuming level 1 = individual and level 2 = site).

[Rutterford, Copas, and Aldridge (2015)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4521133/) mention the following:

> "For example, with continuous
>   outcomes a cluster-level analysis is equivalent to
>   an individual-level analysis if all the clusters are the same
>   size." p. 1053

I used [Optimal Design Software](https://sites.google.com/site/optimaldesignsoftware/home) to calculate the number of clusters needed for a person-level continuous outcome with an effect size of .5 at 90% power and an equal cluster size.

**Would this sample size estimate be the same if the outcome was at the cluster level (assuming a continuous measure and equal allocation, as suggested by Rutterford et al.)? In other words, are the sample size estimates interchangeable for person- and cluster-level outcomes, which is why authors do not usually make this distinction?**

If not, can you recommend a software (preferably a freeware) for calculating the the number of clusters needed for a cluster-randomized trial with cluster level outcomes? I know Optimal Design Software has this feature, but there is no option to change the cluster size, which I feel will be important in the estimate.

Comment: Generally, cluster effects are considered confounders and are used to adjust the person level outcome. Are you seeking to stratify the clusters and look at the primary outcome within each cluster without pooling the overall person-level effect?

Comment: This is precisely what I wish to achieve - except that the cluster-level effect is based on pooling the person-level estimates (e.g., aggregating questionnaire scores).